# Bug in delete vote count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I just clicked the 'delete' button on [a post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16233/5373) that already had 2 votes to delete. A notification box popped up saying:

> Vote to delete this post? (21 votes remaining)

I clicked on 'OK' and the post was promptly deleted, having garnered only 3 delete votes.

This has happened many times before: the number of votes listed as remaining is always much larger than the actual number of votes actually required for it to be deleted. IME, 3 votes from Trusted Users is enough to delete a question, but the notification always says 20 or 21. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Can you include a link to the post(s) in question?

Comment: @Emrakul Sure, I'll edit to do so. (I didn't originally because I prefer not to advertise my downvotes and votes to close/delete as some people take it as a personal attack - especially since this was an edge case and I wasn't entirely sure whether or not to delete it.)

Comment: @Emrakul Link added! Only to the one I deleted today; it's happened loads of times, but it'd be hard for me to track down any more since deleted posts aren't searchable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"21 votes remaining" is referring to how many delete votes *you* have remaining for that day, not the post. That is, you have 21 remaining delete votes that you can use that UTC day.

For more information, see [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192738/180276).

Comment: If I'm right, it's the same for flags! For example I've 14 daily, but the number changes, depending on reputation and old successful flags.

Comment: Thanks. Confusing choice of words - I'm sure I'm not the only one to have misinterpreted it! Maybe someone with a presence on main meta such as yourself could raise it with the higher-ups?